# How can determine a template parameter can be converted into arithmetic type?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, sfinae

I want something work like this:

```
template<typename T, typename = void> // sth like T=>int or T=>double not valid
struct test : std::false_type{};

template<typename T, ???> // what should i do?
struct test<T,???> : std::true_type{};
```

wihich would result in:

```
std::cout << test<int>::value << std::endl;
```

would return "true", and a custom class

```
class a{ int a;double b};
std::cout << test<a>::value << std::endl;
```

would return "false"

Comment: not completely clear. are you looking for [std::is_integral](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) ?

Comment: or maybe `std::is_arithmetic` ?

Comment: Use  std::is_convertible to specialize for the various types?

Comment: i think i am meaning use std::is_convertible to specialize for various types

Comment: This looks like homework.

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk it's not homework, im just taking a simple example to make people understand my thought and question. I really need to learn how to ask a technical question more clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:

- you're asking how to do **SFINAE** to specialize `test`,
- [`std::is_arithmetic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) represents your definition of *convertable to arithmetic type*,

You can use `std::enable_if` for the specialization of `test`:

```
template<typename T> 
struct test<
    T, 
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>> : std::true_type
{ };
```

Comment: what if i also want to support those classes who have a user-defined conversion to arithmetics?

Comment: @TsaoShisong One simple way to do that is add that type in `void_t` also, as it goes `void_t<expr1, expr2, expr3, ...>`.

Comment: Did You try ```is_convertible``` :  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible?

Comment: `void_t<std::enable_if_t<...>>`? Are you sure that's void enough? Why not `void_t<void_t<void_t<void_t<void_t<void_t<std::enable_if_t<...>>>>>>>`?

Comment: @T.C. If you're asking why there's `void_t` introduced, well, you don't really **need** `void_t` in this case. Solo `std::enable_if_t` would be enough. Just have it a way of introducing a new technique.

Comment: @T.C Please look at my edit, and yes, `void_t<void_t<void_t<void_t<void_t<void_t<std::enable_if_t<...>>>>>>>` looks quite void-y then :)

Answer (score 3):

There is always a completely explicit test you can do for implicit conversions

```
namespace detail
{
    std::true_type check(int);
    std::true_type check(float);
    std::true_type check(char);
    // ...
    std::false_type check(...);
}

template<typename T>
struct is_implicitly_convertible_to_arithmetic
    : decltype(::detail::check(std::declval<T>())) {};
```

Which is quite verbose, but fully flexible.

Comment: Variadic argument will result in UB for non-trivial class type.

Comment: @liliscent How so? This is within an unevaluated context

Comment: @PasserBy My bad, I misread your later part, I thought you were calling them directly... No UB here.